# Set lineplot marker for only one line

Tags: python, seaborn, linechart

I am trying to plot a seaborn lineplot with 2 lines: one with markers and one without. In the documentation (https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html), it says that, in order to achieve this, I have to pass the the `markers` parameter as well as setting the `style`.

I tried 2 different approaches:

In the first one, I set the `markers` as `True/False` and pass a `marker='o'` to set the default marker. The problem with this approach is that it does not use the marker. It seems to use a `'-'`
white marker as the default one.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7, 5))
sns.lineplot(data=my_data, x='Date', y='Value', markers={'Series 1': True, 'Series 2': False}, style='Name', marker = 'o')
```

In the second approach, I set the `markers` as `"o" and None`, but it raises a `Value Error: Filled and line art markers cannot be mixed`.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7, 5))
sns.lineplot(data=my_data, x='Date', y='Value', markers={'Series 1': 'o', 'Series 2': None}, style='Name')
```

What is the correct way to achieve the result I want?

Comment: Regarding the second attempt, see https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/v0.12/seaborn/_oldcore.py#L559-L563. None would be a non-filled marker. There is a matplotlib workaround, if you're interested, but it feels like a hack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remember that seaborn is a wrapper on matplotlib, so if an error doesn't make sense or documentation seems incomplete, search the matplotlib documentation.

I found that `[',', '.', 'o', 'v', '^', '<', '>', '8', 's', 'p', '*', 'h', 'H', 'D', 'd', 'P', 'X']` (not an exhaustive list) works as input for the markers and `','` in particular will add a pixel marker which visually looks like no marker (unless you zoom in a lot). Hope this helps.

See example below:

```
import seaborn as sns
flights = sns.load_dataset("flights")
my_data = flights[flights['month'].isin(['Jan', 'Feb'])]
sns.lineplot(data=my_data, x='year', y='passengers', style='month', 
    style_order=['Jan', 'Feb'], markers={'Jan': ',', 'Feb': 'o'}
)
```

[image]